# React event.target setState. Set list item backgroundColor

Tags: reactjs

After clicking on the item list I want to change its background color. After clicking on another, I want the color to return to the default. I did something like that:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Node({expanded, name}) {

    const [targetS, setTargetS] = useState()

    const Select = (element) => {
        const {target} = element

        targetS && targetS.backgroundColor = ''
        setTargetS(target)
        targetS.style.backgroundColor = 'orange'
    }
    return (
        <li onClick={Select}>
            {expanded? '-':'+'} {name}
        </li>

    )
}

export default Node
```

but it doesn't work as I think

Comment: You already have `expanded` property of each item. Why don't you just use same to highlight the item? `className={ expanded ? "bg-orange" : '' }`. I am assuming only one item will remain expanded at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using React, take advantage of writing JavaScript inside the JSX and React state. You don't need to manipulate the color of your element using event object directly. (The way you are doing it needs some correction also). You can let React be responsible for triggering the color change by leveraging react state to act as a toggle for your `li` className.

Create a `activeNode` state and its setter `setActiveNode` in parent component of `Node`. Then pass it as follows:-

`<Node name={name} expanded={expanded} activeNode={activeNode} setActiveNode={setActiveNode}/>`

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'

function Node({expanded, name, setActiveNode, activeNode}) {

    const selectElement = (name) => {
       setActiveNode(name)
    }
    return (
        <li className={activeNode===name?"orange":""} onClick={()=>selectElement(name)}>
            {expanded? '-':'+'} {name}
        </li>
    )
}

export default Node
```

Inside your stylesheet:-

```
orange{
background:"orange"
}
```

Comment: works better, but when I clicked on another a previous element is still orange, so when I clicked on all elements, all are orange

Comment: I understood your requirement now. I have updated the code.